# Undefined method for a 'wink' system

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to setup a system where if User A is reading a status from User B and clicks 'I'm interested' it will send a pre default message to User B's inbox (create new record in the Message table). This is sort of like on social networks where users sends a 'wink' to another user. I was able to do a similar setup for another section on the app that works, but I can't get this 'wink' feature to work. After the user clicks 'I'm interested', that link should no longer be available to the user for that status. I get a `undefined method 'interested=` error.

Intrigued Controller:

```
    def create
      @intrigue = current_user.intrigues.build(intrigue_params)
    end

    def destroy
      @intrigue.destroy
    end

    def repost
      @intrigue = Intrigue.find(params[:id]).repost(current_user)
    end


#Need help with below code

    def interested
      @intrigue = User.find(params[:id])
      @message = Message.create(:subject => "#{user_id} is Interested in you",
                                :sender_id => @user_id,
                                :recipient_id => @intrigue.user_id,
                                :body => "I saw your date and I'm interested")
      @intrigue.message = @message
      render :new, alert: 'Your message was sent.'
    end
```

Routes:

resources :intrigues do
    member do
      post :repost
      post :interested
    end
  end

I added `has_one :intrigue` to the `Message` model.

I added `belongs_to :message` to the `Intrigue` model.

The `intrigues` table has the following columns: `id, content, user_id`

The `messages` table has the following columns: `id, sender_id, recipient_id, subject, body`

Comment: please post the logs for calls to the `interested` action. see more information about how to debug your application here: http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/

Comment: I need help with the code. I have been brainstorming on how to finish this. When I look at `def interested` it does not look correct. I have pieces of what I need but there is something missing.

Comment: on thing that is obvious from your code example is the usage of `user_id` and `@user_id` that is probably wrong.

Comment: Where/how does the interested method gets called? Where does user_id come from? If you try log inside your method, do you get output?

Comment: the user_id is from the user login who clicked the 'I'm interested' link. So if you're User 25, then your id would be the 'user_id' for sender_id. I have the call method wrong since I get a undefined method. `<%= link_to "I'm Interested", interested_intrigue_path(intrigue), method: :message %>`

Comment: are you sure that `intrigue` is not nil?and please, post your routes.rb with the view

Comment: /@intrigue is a User, so should /@intrigue.user_id actually be /@intrigue.id ?

Comment: Do you see this path in `rake routes`? It's telling you that route isn't defined.

Comment: Post your routes file here.

Comment: Ah thank you...it was a misspelling in the routes. I have to find out how to finish sending the message off with `@intrigue.message = @message` in the controller. As I get a `undefined method 'message='`

Comment: Is 'message' listed as an 'attr_accessor' in the appropriate model so you generate getter and setter methods?

Comment: @Fred no I don't have a `attr_accessor` but that's not what's causing the error.  `@intrigue.message = @message` is incorrect. But I need something there to finish the acting so that when user clicks on "I'm Interested" it will automatically send a message to that user notifying someone is interested in them. Also thanks to @David Aldridge for the correction on `@intrigue.id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the line `@intrigue.message = @message`

Your sender id and recipient id are incorrect also.

```
def interested
  @intrigue = User.find(params[:id])
  @intrigue = current_user
  @recipient = Intrigue.find(params[:id])

  @message = Message.create(:subject => "Someone is Interested in you",
                         :sender_id => @intrigue.id,
                         :recipient_id => @recipient.user_id,
                         :body => "I saw your date and I'm interested")
    render :new, alert: 'Your message was sent.'
end
```

That will have it working with no errors. I would also add a redirect.